# combo box selection property change

Tags: wix

I am writing an installer for an application. As part of that I am required to get the country name the user selects. If the user selects United States, I want the value US in my program, i.e. 2 letter code.

Currently I implemented the combo box like this:

```
<Control Id="CountryList" Type="ComboBox" Sorted="yes" ComboList="yes" Property="COUNTRY" X="30" Y="118" Width="150" Height="15">
  <ComboBox Property="COUNTRY">
     <ListItem Value="United States" />
     <ListItem Value="India" />
     <ListItem Value="Australia" />
     <ListItem Value="United Kingdom" />
  </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to change the property `COUNTRY` to `US` or `IN` or `UK` etc. I mean 2 letter code.

Also I have to add all possible countries. Any better way to accomplish this?

Related to this, I want the first combobox to list all the countries. The second combobox can then show the states that belong to the country. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Use the `Text` attribute for a visible text, and `Value` attribute for the value](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_listitem.htm) to be put into the `ComboBox` property when the item is selected:

```
<Control Id="CountryList" Type="ComboBox" Sorted="yes" ComboList="yes" Property="COUNTRY" X="30" Y="118" Width="150" Height="15">
  <ComboBox Property="COUNTRY">
    <ListItem Text="United States" Value="US" />
    <ListItem Text="United Kingdom" Value="UK" />
    ...
  </ComboBox>
</Control>
```

As for your other questions:

> Also I have to add all possible countries. Any better way to
>   accomplish this?

You can take inspiration from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978607/get-country-list-in-other-languages-besides-english) and add a build-time step to generate an XML fragment of `<ListItem>` elements.

> The second combobox can then show the states that belong to the
>   country.

Note that there's no way to catch the event when a selected item is changed in a combobox. That's a well-known limitation of the MSI UI. You can try to achieve what you want with the workaround I call "twin-dialogs". See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241863/wix-interactions-with-conditions-properties-custom-actions) for more information.